# php shopping cart display error

Tags: php, shopping-cart

First of all, i am sorry if this question has been asked before.I am working on a shopping cart. My current code will only show 1 item in the cart. It means that when i click add to cart on #product1 it will show me #product1 detail in the cart. However when i click add to cart for #product2, it will override the information of #product1.

Here is my code for product:

```
<div >
                    <image src="ip5s.jpg">
                    <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspIphone 5S</font></p>
                    <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
                    <p><form name="addcart" method="post" action="processcart.php">
                    <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1234" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
                    </form>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Here is the code for process.php:

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
 include_once("config.php"); 
 $pid=$_POST['product_id'];
 $_SESSION['product'] = array($pid);
 sleep(2);
 echo "Add to cart successful";
 header("refresh:1;url=cart.php");
 exit();
?>
```

Here is the code for cart.php:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
  echo "<p>Your shopping cart is empty!</p>";
  else{
  $tblname="products";
  require_once("dbcon.php");
  $proids = array();

  foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $id)
    {
    $proids[] = $id;
    }
   $proids = implode(',', $proids);
   $query = "SELECT * from $tblname where product_id in ('$proids') ";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


   echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row[$i]['product_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row[$i]['product_price'] . "</td></tr>" ;
        }
   echo "</table>";
   mysql_free_result($result);
   mysql_close();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `session_start()` **to the beginning of** `cart.php` to resume the session.

Also, in order to add multiple product IDs to the `$_SESSION['product']` variable, which is probably what you'll be doing, you'll have to change
`$_SESSION['product'] = array($pid);`

to

```
$_SESSION['product'][] = $pid;
```

Which inserts `$pid` to the end of `$_SESSION['product']` array.

Answer (score 0):

USE [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/array_push) .make an array with card Ids and display them using forloop

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
$pid = $_POST['product_id'];
$_SESSION['product'] = array();
$_SESSION['product'] = array_push($_SESSION['product'], $pid);
sleep(2);
echo "Add to cart successful";
header("refresh:1;url=cart.php");
exit();
?>
```

Try

```
 <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['quantity']))
$_SESSION['quantity']=$_SESSION['quantity']+1;
else
$_SESSION['quantity']=1;
echo "Cart=". $_SESSION['quantity'];
?>
```

Comment: The syntax is `array_push($_SESSION['product'], $pid);` or `$_SESSION['product'][] = $pid`

Comment: @AzizAG yes.Updated :)

Comment: Actually you should only keep ` array_push($_SESSION['product'], $pid);` as `array_push` only returns the last inserted element, so basically, you're overwriting `$_SESSION['product']` every time with the last inserted `$pid`.

Comment: i modify with the code you provided,but now it show me that invalid argument supplied to foreach loop

Comment: can you var_dump($_SESSION['product']) after updated 2,3 CARTS ?

Comment: It wont update the cart now,there is something wrong with the loop im using

Comment: it just show me this=>Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: please remove foreach for now and var_dump($_SESSION['product'])

Comment: just remove foreach loop and replace with var_dump($_SESSION['product']) ?

Comment: and i think there is something wrong with $_SESSION['product'] = array_push($_SESSION['product'],$pid); because it show me=>Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: `$_SESSION['product'] = array();` added this line

Comment: int(1) mean One integer.Can you update your cart again and see ?

Comment: `echo "Cart=". $_SESSION['quantity'];` will increase by one after add item to cart

Comment: This is working on the quantity part.But how about the product display part?

Comment: @samitha can you help me to display multiple item?i still cant do it

Comment: you need at least 20 rep to the chat.if you can it's easy for me

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be really stuck on this:

**process_cart.php**

```
<?php

 session_start(); 
 include_once("config.php"); 

 // test & generate cart if needed
 if(! isset($_SESSION['cart']))
   {
   $_SESSION['cart'] = array("products"=>array());
   }

// add current product
// ! note: you need to add data validation to this to avoid SQL injects
 $_SESSION['products'][$_POST['product_id']] = $_POST['quantity'];

// Show you have done something
sleep(2);
echo "Add to cart successful";
header("refresh:1;url=cart.php");

exit();
?>
```

**databaseConnection.php**

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "onlinestore");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
?>
```

**cart.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
  {
  // No items yet added to the cart
  echo "<p>Your shopping cart is empty!</p>";
  }
else
  {
  // set table
  $tblname = "products";

  // get connection
  require_once('DatabaseConnection.php');

  // create a list with product ID's
  $prodids = array();
  // For each product in the cart
  foreach($_SESSION['cart']['products'] as $id => $qntity)
    {
    // add id to the array
    $prodids[] = $id;
    }

  // combine into a string
  $prodids = implode(',', $prodids);

  $query = "SELECT * from $tblname where product_id in ($prodids) ";

  // (The query should really be mysqli)
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<table>";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_price'] . "</td></tr>". $_SESSION['cart']['products'][$row['product_id']];
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: it still show me the same problem saying that invalid argument supplied to foreach loop

Comment: What do you get when you put print_r($_SESSION); directly after the session_start() in cart.php ?

Comment: Array ( [product] => Array ( [0] => 1234 ) [cart] => 1 [products] => Array ( [1234] => 1 ) ) this is what i get

Comment: Strange. I think you are getting some information from old sessions. add session_destroy(); directly after session_start in cart.php. Reload the page. Then remove this line, and add a product. See what happens

Comment: (Or close all browser windows and open the page anew)

Comment: Check whether the query created is valid and runs. Add a few echo statements to the diferent steps in the file to see where it gets stuck. I see no reason why it would not produce output.

Comment: i already checked for several times,but it just end up nothing display. Nevermind,thank you for the help.